# Calculate new columns in a Pandas DataFrame using row number

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, apply

I am trying to create two new probability distribution columns to A and B which need to follow the time series (indexed here).

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

p = 4.0
q = 5.0
a = np.array([0,0,0,1,0])
b = np.array([0,0,1,1,0])
d = {'A':a, 'B':b}
Time_Interval = pd.timedelta_range('11:00:00', periods=5, freq='10T')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, Time_Interval)
```

**The new col A' (corresponding to A) is generated as follow**.

```
so when i = 1 ==> poisson.pmf(0, p*1/5)
        i = 2 ==> poisson.pmf(0, p*2/5)
        i = 3 ==> poisson.pmf(0, p*3/5)
        i = 4 ==> poisson.pmf(1, p*4/5)
        i = 5 ==> poisson.pmf(0, p*5/5)
```

I tried the following way.

```
df["A'"] = df.A.apply(lambda v : poisson.pmf(v, p*i/len(df)) for i in list(range(1,1+len(df['A']))))
df["B'"] = df.B.apply(lambda x : poisson.pmf(x, q*j/len(df)) for j in list(range(1,1+len(df['B']))))


## list(range(1, len(df['A']))) creates the index i for the i/len(df) term inside the poisson func. for i [1,2,3,4,5].
```

But I will get the following error.

```
TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

**The outcome should look like this**

```
df
Out[358]: 
               A       B   A'         B'
11:00:00       0       0  0.449329  0.367879
11:10:00       0       0  0.201897  0.135335
11:20:00       0       1  0.090718  0.149361
11:30:00       1       1  0.130439  0.073263
11:40:00       0       0  0.018316  0.006738
```

Comment: I don't know much about pandas, but I think you can do something easy, don't use lambda if you have lot of things to do with youe function, it makes the code hard to write, understand and edit later, just create a function and use it inside with panads' apply method:

def my_function(*args, **kwargs):
    #your code here

df["A'"] = df['A'].apply(my_function)

Comment: Did you mean `poisson.pmf(…i…) for i in …`, instead of `poisson.pmf(…i…), i in …`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I meant poisson.pmf(…i…) for i in …

Comment: So did changing `,` to `for` solve your problem?

Comment: I get TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` value needs to be the row index that's supplying your `v` parameter. The code you have iterates through all rows in each calculation.

To solve this you need row numbers in your data frame:

```
d = {'t': Time_Interval, 'A':a, 'B':b}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then you can process the whole row and look up the row number (`row.name`):

```
def func(row):
    i = row.name + 1
    return poisson.pmf(row['A'], p*i/len(df))

df["A'"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

I'll leave handling column B to you. (Hint: you can pass `args` to `apply` and they get appended to `func`'s arguments.)